# Finding the date of the next Saturday

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

How would one go about finding the date of the next Saturday in Python? Preferably using `datetime` and in the format '2013-05-25'?

Comment: Google around a little before you post here. Check this out. See if its useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436840/how-to-calculate-next-friday-at-3am

Comment: Thanks, saw that before but I don't need the time and was wondering whether there was a more concise way.

Comment: This link helps, my apologies for wasting time. If anyone has a better solution feel free to answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801084/how-to-calculate-next-friday-in-python

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> d = datetime.strptime('2013-05-27', '%Y-%m-%d') # Monday
>>> t = timedelta((12 - d.weekday()) % 7)
>>> d + t
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 1, 0, 0)
>>> (d + t).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2013-06-01'
```

I use `(12 - d.weekday()) % 7` to compute the delta in days between given day and next Saturday because `weekday` is between 0 (Monday) and 6 (Sunday), so Saturday is 5. But:

- 5 and 12 are the same modulo 7 (yes, we have 7 days in a week :-) )
- so `12 - d.weekday()` is between 6 and 12 where `5 - d.weekday()` would be between 5 and -1
- so this allows me not to handle the negative case (-1 for Sunday).

Here is a very simple version (no check) for any weekday:

```
>>> def get_next_weekday(startdate, weekday):
    """
    @startdate: given date, in format '2013-05-25'
    @weekday: week day as a integer, between 0 (Monday) to 6 (Sunday)
    """
    d = datetime.strptime(startdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    t = timedelta((7 + weekday - d.weekday()) % 7)
    return (d + t).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

>>> get_next_weekday('2013-05-27', 5) # 5 = Saturday
'2013-06-01'
```

Comment: There's no need to add the modulo base (7) to avoid negative numbers. ["The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand."](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#:~:text=the%20modulo%20operator%20always%20yields%20a%20result%20with%20the%20same%20sign%20as%20its%20second%20operand)

Comment: @Mattwmaster58: didn't know, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I found this [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) pretty useful. Just one line

```py
In [4]: pendulum.now().next(pendulum.SATURDAY).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[4]: '2019-04-27'
```

See below for more details:

```py
In [1]: import pendulum

In [2]: pendulum.now()
Out[2]: DateTime(2019, 4, 24, 17, 28, 13, 776007, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))

In [3]: pendulum.now().next(pendulum.SATURDAY)
Out[3]: DateTime(2019, 4, 27, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))

In [4]: pendulum.now().next(pendulum.SATURDAY).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[4]: '2019-04-27'
```

Comment: This is best. There are many SO posts like this and its a bog of confusing implementations.

Answer (score 4):

You need two main packages,

```
import datetime
import calendar
```

Once you have those, you can simply get the desired date for the week by the following code,

```
today = datetime.date.today() #reference point. 
saturday = today + datetime.timedelta((calendar.SATURDAY-today.weekday()) % 7 )
saturday
```

**Bonus**
Following the content, if you type

```
saturday.weekday()
```

It will result `5`.
Therefore, you can also use `5` in place of `calendar.SATURDAY` and you will get same result.

`saturday = today + datetime.timedelta((5-today.weekday()) % 7 )`

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the date from today (inspired from Emanuelle )

```
def get_next_weekday(weekday_number):
    """
    @weekday: week day as a integer, between 0 (Monday) to 6 (Sunday)
    """
    assert 0 <= weekday_number <= 6
    today_date = datetime.today()
    next_week_day = timedelta((7 + weekday_number - today_date.weekday()) % 7)
    return (today_date + next_week_day).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, based on Emmanuel's example, but making 0-6 conform to your week:

```
ScheduleShift = -1 # make Saturday end of week
EndofWeekDay = lambda do : do + datetime.timedelta( ( ScheduleShift + (13 -  do.weekday() ) %7 ) )
```

Which can be called with:

```
EndofWeekDay( datetime.date.today() )
```

returning a datetime.date object

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share a code. With this, you will get a list of dates when Saturday days will be in the next 10 days.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
target_day = 'Saturday'
now_ = datetime.today().date()
how_many_days = 10
next_date = [now_ + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(how_many_days) if (now_ + timedelta(days=x)).strftime("%A") == target_day]
print(next_date)
```