# How can I find the next day that will be a certain weekday (the next time it will be Monday, for instance)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Given a day of the week (Monday, for instance), how do I find the next day that will be that weekday (as a `datetime` object)?

Comment: Did you try the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770463/5478462

Answer (score 0):

I just asked the question so people could see my solution as a function if they needed it. It uses the Python datetime module, and returns a datetime for the next day it will be that weekday.

```
def find_next_weekday(weekday_to_find): #with a string day of the week (full day of week, ie 'Monday'), return the next datetime object that will match that day
    now = datetime.datetime.now() #Right now as a datetime object
    for i in range(1,8):#the next instance of a weekday will have to be within this range
        weekday = now + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
        if (weekday.strftime("%A") == weekday_to_find):
            return weekday
```